# Flutter retrieve data from firestore as a list

Tags: flutter

I have been struggling for hours now to retrieve data from `firestore` as a list so I can show them in a search bar suggestion.

This below function will retrieve data from `firestore` and return some selected fields as a list.

```
Future<List> getNewsOnSearchBar() async {
  final String _collection = 'news';
  final Firestore _fireStore = Firestore.instance;
  var newsList = [];

  print("1");

  Future<QuerySnapshot> getData() async {
    print("2");
    return await _fireStore.collection(_collection).getDocuments();
  }

  QuerySnapshot val = await getData();
  if (val.documents.length > 0) {
    print("3");
    for (int i = 0; i < val.documents.length; i++) {
      newsList.add(val.documents[i].data["headline"]);
    }
  } else {
    print("Not Found");
  }
  print("4");
  return newsList;
}
```

And below is my Search bar `widget`. It has an attribute `searchList` which is of type `List<dynamic>`. It accept values such as:

var list = ["a", "b", "c"];

```
searchList: list
```

So I want to call that above function `getNewsOnSearchBar()` and set the list to the attribute `searchList`. I tried below and it doesn't work.

```
Widget _showSearchBar(BuildContext context) {
  return FutureBuilder(
      future: getNewsOnSearchBar(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError || !snapshot.hasData) {
          return _progressIndicator();
        } else {
          return GFSearchBar(

            searchList: [], //how can I assign the list return from `getNewsOnSearchBar()` here?
            searchQueryBuilder: (query, list) {
              return list
                  .where((item) =>
                      item.toLowerCase().contains(query.toLowerCase()))
                  .toList();
            },
            overlaySearchListItemBuilder: (item) {
              return Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3),
                child: Text(
                  item,
                  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                ),
              );
            },
            onItemSelected: (item) {},
          );
        }
      });
}
```

Could you help me, Please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your function getNewsOnSearchBar() is returning a list, you can use snapshot.data.
so your function becomes something like this

```
return GFSearchBar(
        searchList: snapshot.data,
        searchQueryBuilder: (query, list) {
          return list
              .where((item) =>
                  item.toLowerCase().contains(query.toLowerCase()))
              .toList();
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in two ways.
1-you can retrieve the documents for firebase and then you can use the Map function to create a list.
2-You can create a Firebase Functions to retrieve the information as you expect.

Comment: Can you please provide examples on these two methods? I am new to flutter and this is where I am being stuck. Just a little help please?

Comment: Yes of course,this is an example code to retrieve documents from Firebase and then map it to a class.

Comment: where is the example?